# Creating two instances of SimpleJdbcCall in Guice Service Module

Tags: jetty, guice

I am using postgreSql stored procedures for performing changes to database and connecting to it using SimpleJdbcCall. Now i need to create several instances of it based on procedure I am calling.

My Launcher file Service Module has following methods :

```
@Provides
@Inject
@Named("jdbcTemplate")
JdbcTemplate provideJDBCClient(){return new JdbcTemplate()}

@Provides
@Inject
@Named("aTypeSimpleJdbcCall")
SimpleJdbcCall getSimpleJdbcCallForTypeA(@Named("jdbcTemplate")) {
      SimpleJdbcCall simpleJdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate);
      simpleJdbcCall.setSchema("some");
      simpleJdbcCall.setProcedureName("someName");
      return simpleJdbcCall;
}

@Provides
@Inject
@Named("bTypeSimpleJdbcCall")
SimpleJdbcCall getSimpleJdbcCallForTypeB(@Named("jdbcTemplate")) {
      SimpleJdbcCall simpleJdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate);
      simpleJdbcCall.setSchema("some");
      simpleJdbcCall.setProcedureName("someOtherName");
      return simpleJdbcCall;
}
```

Now in class where I need these objects to call excecute method, I am referring these objects like this :

```
@Inject
@Named("aTypeSimpleJdbcCall")
private SimpleJdbcCall simpleJdbcCallForTypeA;

@Inject
@Named("bTypeSimpleJdbcCall")
private SimpleJdbcCall simpleJdbcCallForTypeB;

@Inject
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
```

I am getting these objects properly as expected and my services are working fine.

What is better way of doing this ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. As it currently stands, this question is likely to be closed because it is primarily opinion based. Can you please edit it to try to ask a more specific, answerable question? You can also consider the [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) stackexchange, but please remember to follow their [rules](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) for questions.

Comment: A few quick notes, you don't need the Inject annotation on Provides methods, and I would recommend researching construction injection (bearing in mind that Guice will automatically instantiate and inject a class if it has a no-argument constructor, no binding or Provides needed!).